# Combine two or more images that partially overlap

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ffmpeg, imagemagick, image-manipulation

Having two or more images that partially overlap, like in this screenshot, I want to combine/merge them into one:

[image: overlapping images]

The coloured squares would be the source images, in lossless format, and no rotation is required.

The result I want is like using the "Auto-Blend Layers" command from Adobe Photoshop, so auto-align and auto-blend is performed automatically:

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/combine-images-auto-blend-layers.html

Comment: I want it to automatically detect the blending parameters, so it detects automatically where each image belongs and auto-align and then auto-blend.

Comment: for that you could use OpenCV, for example: https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d8/d19/tutorial_stitcher.html. You should try it and post some code if if you get stuck, otherwise the question is too broad.

Comment: What format are the original images in - JPEG? PNG?

Comment: We suppose them in PNG with loseless quality.

Comment: Could the images need rotating in order to fit together?

Comment: the overlap between left and right is a bit low but still might work with stitcher or manual keypoint matching.

Comment: No rotating needed.

Comment: Do we know the exact dimensions of the output file or any other useful information that would decrease the complexity?

Comment: Another option could possibly be [hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Hugin is great but requires to manually align all pieces, while cv::Stitcher is automatic, at least for simple operations. Hugin is too much professional.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all for the comments. The software that suits best in this case is `OpenCV` with the `cv::Stitcher` API as @aergustal pointed out. It works extremely well provided that pictures have a decent overlapping, otherwise the following error will be displayed:

`Can't stitch images, error code = 1`

Note that to be able to use the `./cpp-example-stitching` command, you have to compile it from source code. Even Windows doesn't come with it precompiled, at least the version I've downloaded. More information:

[High level stitching API (Stitcher class)](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d8/d19/tutorial_stitcher.html)

Comment: Do the images need to be pixel perfect? Means do they need to be actually from the same image or can the user take a picture with the cam and slightly move the camera and take another pic and combine them? (Different noise, light, skew..)

Comment: @Suisse no idea if there's a margin of discrepancy I'm sure there is. If doesn't work Adobe Photoshop and GIMP have plugins to auto-align layers.